# Change bar graph x label in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graph, bar-chart

Suppose that we have this data:

```
89.9    81.9    90.3
87.6    84.6    87.7
87.3    83.0    87.6
89.7    74.3    90.6
```

Output bar graph:

[image]

How can i change `xlabel` 1,2,3 and 4 default values to some strings like A,B,C and D?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the x-tick labels of the current axis

```
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'one', 'two', 'three', 'four'})
```

`gca` gets the current axis, so on your bar graph this would produce:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Create a Beautiful Bar Graph with Text Label Using Matlab](http://fstang.me/utilities/2013/10/01/matlab-draw.html)

This is a very helpful tutorial you can see.